# HTML Bootstrap tab-content link 'freezes' after first click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap's `list-group` to build a page navigation feature on my HTML page.

Am trying to build a nested bootstrap list-group.

However the link inside the `tab-content` div class works only on first click.

On second click, the link 'freezes' and won't work unless I refresh the page.

The page looks like below.

[image]

Could someone please help me to spot where the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
          <a id="list-home-page" data-toggle="list" href="#aa" role="tab" aria-controls="a">
          A
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
          <a id="list-profile-page" data-toggle="list" href="#bb" role="tab" aria-controls="b">
          B
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabPage">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="aa" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-page">
    New A
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bb" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-page">
    New B
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide working snippet.

Comment: I've attached a photo.

Comment: Could you please provide more brief as looking from code i can see that you are trying to create nested list group or else so please provide more info.

Comment: Yes! It's a nested bootstrap list group.

Comment: ok and what kind of functionality you want i.e when user click on home tab then it will toggle A or B and what about  New A and New B ?